# How to share a postgreSQL database?

Tags: postgresql

I'm currently working on a project with some colleagues and a colleague of mine linked a database created in her postgreSQL server to our visual studio project, but we don't know how she can share the database with the rest of us, or how can we modify the database without having it.
We're using postgreSQL 14.

Comment: Are you trying to access the database created by your colleague remotely? What type of privilege do you want on the database like READ-ONLY or READ-WRITE or even DDL? Is the remote host in your network? Can you do an ICMP check?(ping <postgres_sql_host_ip>? If you can answer these , I can list out the steps that you need to execute in the database.

Comment: Put the database on a server machine that can be accessed by all clients.

Comment: Proceed with caution: do not use anything but a db with a mock up data while developing the code. If you want to just test the connection do not start with modifying the data. Even for the mockup db have some backup from which the db could be restored in no time. If you run `SELECT` tomorrow it is great to know that it will return the same records as today passing the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to create your `database` in a cloud provider such as `AWS`.

You can take a look at: https://aws.amazon.com/rds/postgresql/

This way all of you will be able to access the `database`.

Answer (score 0):

Server Setup:

Ensure PostgreSQL server is accessible from the network.
Configure postgresql.conf to listen on all IP addresses.
Add IP entries in pg_hba.conf for your colleagues.
Connection String:

Share the PostgreSQL connection string with your colleagues.
Firewall:

Allow incoming connections on the PostgreSQL port in the firewall.
Visual Studio:

Configure the Visual Studio project with the provided connection string.
Sharing Schema:

Share SQL script to create schema and initial data.
Version Control:

Use version control for database schema changes (e.g., Flyway, Liquibase).
Collaboration:

Coordinate changes using database migrations.
Backup:

Regularly back up the database and share backup files.